# ¿Cómo realizar el Binding HTLM en un tabla creada dinámicamente con Angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular8

Estoy creando una tabla en *Angular 8*, la cual tengo algo así

```
<table [className]="isActivities ?  'principalInboxProx' : 'principalInbox'" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td *ngIf="isActivities" class="tdTablaProx">
                            <div *ngIf="item.respid === -1" class="avatar system icon avatar-no-margin" title="Agendamientos">
                                <i class="dx-icon dx-icon-event"></i>
                            </div>
                            <ng-container *ngIf="item.respid !== -1 && item.creaid === null">
                                <div class="avatar system" title="Au">Au</div>
                                <div class="avatar" [title]="item.respds">{{item.respds | avatar}}</div>
                            </ng-container>
                            <ng-container *ngIf="item.respid !== -1 && item.creaid !== null">
                                <div class="avatar" [title]="item.creads">{{item.creads | avatar}}</div>
                                <div class="avatar" [title]="item.respds">{{item.respds | avatar}}</div>
                            </ng-container>
                        </td>
                        <td [className]="isActivities ?  'noneClassJx4' : 'tdTabla'">
                            <h3 class="titleInboxFull"><a href=""> {{item.descripcion}} </a></h3>
                        </td>
                        <td [innerHTML]="item.gridResult"></td>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

El problema surge en que dinámicamente en una propiedad del objeto retorno un `string` que puede contener más de una columna y quisiera poder insertarlo donde hago el `innerHTML`

```
item.gridResult : '<td>#325</td>
<td><SPAN class = "label label-info">Proceso Iniciado</SPAN></td>
<td><SPAN class = "label label-success">Estado completo</SPAN></td>'
```

Pero viendo el inspector html del browser, únicamente se crea un `TD`

```
<table style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;" class="principalInbox">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <!--bindings={
              "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
            }-->
            <td class="tdTabla">
                <h3 class="titleInboxFull">
                    <a href=""> prueba cargue archivo con caracteres especiales </a>
                </h3>
            </td>
            <td> <!-- acá deberían crearse las columnas del string del objeto--> 
                #325
                <span class="label label-info">Proceso Iniciado</span>
                <span class="label label-success">Estado completo</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: quizá es porque en un `td` no puedes tener `td` hijos

Comment: claro, pero quisiera poder reemplazar ese `td` con los valores que retorno; si uso `div` tampoco agrega los `td`